# Comparação entre mês e ano

Tags: php

Preciso comparar apenas o ano e mês entre duas datas, eu fiz do seguinte jeito e funciona perfeitamente:

```
$mes1 = "2018/02";
$mes2 = "2018/03";

if($mes1 > $mes2) {

    echo "Mês 1 é maior que mês 2";

}elseif($mes2 > $mes1) {

    echo "Mês 2 é maior que mês 1";

}
```

Minha duvida é sobre boas prátias, comparar apenas o ano e mês desse jeito esta correto ou eu precisaria usar algum recurso do `php` para dizer que se trata de uma data? meu medo é disso começar a dar erro em alguma versão do `php` futura.

OBS: minha duvida é justamente pela falta do "dia" nessa comparação, todas as comparações que eu vi elas possuem ano, mês e dia, a minha não tem o dia

> Eu sei que existem várias postagens que podem parecer parecidas com
>   essa, porem não são.

Comment: o que lhe custaria concatenar o dia na variável e torná-la uma data e trabalhar corretamente com datas no PHP?

Comment: Eu não preciso do dia, a comparação precisa ser apenas entre os meses, eu preciso disso pra poder tentar determinar a diferença de meses que uma data tem da outra

Comment: não estou dizendo que precisa do dia, estou dizendo pra concatenar qq dia na variavl pra tornar ela em uma data. pode ser qq para as duas variaveis. dai compara como data no php

Answer (score 0):

A comparação vai funcionar em qualquer versão, porque você está comparando strings, e o caractere mais significativo está a esquerda, enquanto o caractere menos significativo está a direita.

É uma boa prática? Não, datas geralmente são convertidas em inteiros (timestamp) e então comparadas para maior flexibilidade.

Comment: Eu estou tentando descobrir a diferença de meses que uma data tem da outra, o problema é que me retorna um erro, vc sabe o que pode ser?
código:
$mes1 = new DateTime( '2018-03-15' );
$mes2 = new DateTime( '2018-02-22' );

$intervalo = $mes1->diff( $mes2 );

erro: 
Error Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to string on line number 11

Answer (score 0):

Jovem,

Sua solução não está errada, porém o PHP conta com funções prontas para agilizar e deixar as coisas transparentes para, por exemplo, depois lidar com o dado inserindo em um MySQL da vida..

Fiz um exemplo, espero que o ajude:

```
<?php
   $mes1 = '2001-03-21';
   $mes2 = '2014-05-21';

   $data = new DateTime($mes1); // Data de Nascimento
   $nova_data = $data->diff(new DateTime($mes2));
   $calculo = $nova_data->format('%m');

   $total_meses = $calculo;

   echo $total_meses;

?>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas eu tive um probleminha, nessa comparação por exemplo eu esperava receber a diferença de 15 meses, porem eu recebo apenas de 3: $mes1 = '2018-11-21';
   $mes2 = '2020-02-21';

Answer (score 0):

Concatene um dia qualquer nas duas datas, transforme-as em datas válidas no PHP e faça a comparação com strtotime.

```
$dia="-01";

$mes1 = "2018/02".$dia;
$mes2 = "2018/03".$dia;


$mes1 = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $mes1));

$mes2 = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $mes2));



if($mes1 > $mes2) {

    echo "Mês 1 é maior que mês 2";

}elseif($mes2 > $mes1) {

    echo "Mês 2 é maior que mês 1";

}
```

https://ideone.com/U4tkHI